# No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.2.0/modules.builtin'

Tags: kernel, kubernetes

I'm trying to install Kubernetes cluster using Kubespray. I get this error during script run time:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.2.0/modules.builtin'
```

I use for control plane and work node Ubuntu 22.04.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

I use this OS: https://src.openvz.org/projects/OVZT/repos/ubuntu-22.04-x86_64-ez/browse

Comment: Are you trying to run this inside an OpenVZ containerized Ubuntu?  I don't think K8s fully supports properly running inside an OVZ container of Ubuntu.

Comment: yes, correct. For test environment it should be used only.

Comment: I would suggest that you avoid attempting this in an OVZ container.  OVZ containers have weird caveats and are not fully virtualized so you will run into odd issues with k8s and KVM and such.  is it an option to get a KVM driven system for this?  I have seen so many OVZ issues in general with recent Ubuntu containers in them that I cannot safely suggest using OVZ to deploy K8s or Ubuntu inside it.

Comment: at this point no. Can you advise how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Crossposted: https://serverfault.com/questions/1125461/no-such-file-or-directory-lib-modules-5-2-0-modules-builtin and https://superuser.com/questions/1772223/no-such-file-or-directory-lib-modules-5-2-0-modules-builtin - Pick *ONE* site to ask this on.  Not more than one.

Comment: ok, I got your point. About the issue. What you can advise for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. i had the same error.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-01] (item=ip_vs) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-02] (item=ip_vs) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-03] (item=ip_vs) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-01] (item=ip_vs_rr) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_rr", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_rr", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-03] (item=ip_vs_rr) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_rr", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_rr", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-02] (item=ip_vs_rr) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_rr", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_rr", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-01] (item=ip_vs_wrr) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_wrr", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_wrr", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-03] (item=ip_vs_wrr) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_wrr", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_wrr", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-02] (item=ip_vs_wrr) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_wrr", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_wrr", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-01] (item=ip_vs_sh) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_sh", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_sh", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-03] (item=ip_vs_sh) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_sh", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_sh", "params": "", "state": "present"}
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'
failed: [nl-k8-02] (item=ip_vs_sh) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "ip_vs_sh", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lib/modules/5.15.0-73-generic/modules.builtin'", "name": "ip_vs_sh", "params": "", "state": "present"}
```

the reason was i tried to install k8s via kubespray  inside **lxd container**.
thats why of course  the folder /lib/modules was empty inside lxd container.

i dont know your case but:

- if you try to install k8s on usual linux host then file "modules.builtin"
  is a part of package "linux-modules-5.2.0-generic"
- if you try to install k8s inside lxd container then go back to the
  main host and load the following kernel modules:
  br_netfilter
  ip_vs
  ip_vs_rr
  ip_vs_wrr
  ip_vs_sh
  nf_conntrack

to be sure they are loaded every host boot use the following

```
# cat /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf  | grep -v '#'

br_netfilter
ip_vs
ip_vs_rr
ip_vs_wrr
ip_vs_sh
nf_conntrack

#  systemctl restart systemd-modules-load
#  systemctl status  systemd-modules-load
```

the file in ansible that generates the error is the following:

```
$kubespray_folder/kubespray/roles/kubernetes/node/tasks/main.yml
```

hope it helps as it has done to me